# How to add legend for single or multi series chart in Vega Lite?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

How do I add a legend to a basic chart in Vega?

I'm using Vega in the web app where I want all my charts to include a legend even if its a single series.

i.e in Google Sheets it looks like [image]

Comment: You can just add a legend even if all values have the same value for a field.

Comment: Can you give an example of code that would work with https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/bar

Comment: Check out https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/legends/. You need to add both a scale and a legend. I think Vega-Lite (https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/) may be a better fit for you. It generates a legend if you use a color encoding.

Comment: I took a look at the legends documentation before posting the stack overflow question and tried different options but I haven’t been able to get what I wanted. I want a single series basic bar chart with no color encoding to have the legend enabled.

Comment: In Vega, you need a scale to get a legend. In Vega-Lite, you need a color, shape, or opacity encoding.

Comment: Answered in https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3411

Comment: @dominik Just wondering has datum been implemented yet? Because I saw that the github issue has been closed saying its a special case for https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/1601

Comment: The issue is still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Datum hasn't been implemented yet I added an extra layer as a workaround (This also works for Multi Series Charts by adding additional values into data.values for the rule.)

```
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "rule"
          },
          "data": {
            "values": [
              {
                "color": "Total Units"
              }
            ]
          },
          "encoding": {
            "color": {
              "field": "color", 
              // If you want to update the color of the legend...
              "scale": {"range": ["blue", "#000"]}, 
              "sort": false,
              "type": "nominal",
              "legend": { "title": "" }
            } 
          }
        }
```

Also for those that want to view an example in VegaLite Editor https://vega.github.io/editor/#/

```
{
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {
            "goal": 25,
            "project": "a",
            "score": 25
          },
          {
            "goal": 47,
            "project": "b",
            "score": 57
          },
          {
            "goal": 30,
            "project": "c",
            "score": 23
          },
          {
            "goal": 27,
            "project": "d",
            "score": 19
          }
        ]
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "type": "nominal",
          "field": "project"
        },
        "y": {
          "type": "quantitative",
          "field": "score"
        }
      },
      "height": 300,
      "width": 400
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "rule"
      },
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {
            "color": "Goal"
          }
        ]
      },
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "color", 
          "sort": false,
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": { "title": "" }
        } 
      }
    }
  ]
}
```